# Apache Spark - How to define a UserDefinedAggregateFunction after 3?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using Spark 3.0, and in order to use a user-defined function as a window function, I need an instance of `UserDefinedAggregateFunction`. Initially I thought that using the new `Aggregator` and `udaf` would solve this problem (as shown [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/sql-ref-functions-udf-aggregate.html)), but `udaf` returns a `UserDefinedFunction`, not a `UserDefinedAggregateFunction`.

Since Spark 3.0, `UserDefinedAggregateFunction` is deprecated, as stated [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/expressions/UserDefinedAggregateFunction.html) (despite being possible to still [find it around](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/udaf-scala.html))

So the question is: is there a correct (not deprecated) way in Spark 3.0 to define a proper `UserDefinedAggregateFunction` and use it as a window function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Spark 3, the new API uses [`Aggregator`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/expressions/Aggregator.html) to define user-defined aggregations:

> *abstract class* `Aggregator[-IN, BUF, OUT]` *extends Serializable*:
>
> A base class for user-defined aggregations, which can be used in
> Dataset operations to take all of the elements of a group and reduce
> them to a single value.

Aggregator brings performance improvements comparing to deprecated UDAF. You can see the issue [Efficient User Defined Aggregators](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-27296).

Here's an example on how to define a mean Aggregator and register it using `functions.udaf` method:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Aggregator

val meanAgg= new Aggregator[Long, (Long, Long), Double]() {
    
    def zero = (0L, 0L) // Init the buffer
  
    def reduce(y: (Long, Long), x: Long) = (y._1 + x, y._2 + 1)

    def merge(a: (Long, Long), b: (Long, Long)) = (a._1 + b._1, a._2 + b._2)

    def finish(r: (Long, Long)) = r._1.toDouble / r._2
  
    def bufferEncoder: Encoder[(Long, Long)] = implicitly(ExpressionEncoder[(Long, Long)])

    def outputEncoder: Encoder[Double] = implicitly(ExpressionEncoder[Double])
}

val meanUdaf = udaf(meanAgg)
```

Using it with Window:

```
val df = Seq(
  (1, 2), (1, 5),
  (2, 3), (2, 1),
).toDF("id", "value")
    
df.withColumn("mean", meanUdaf($"value").over(Window.partitionBy($"id"))).show
//+---+-----+----+
//| id|value|mean|
//+---+-----+----+
//|  1|    2| 3.5|
//|  1|    5| 3.5|
//|  2|    3| 2.0|
//|  2|    1| 2.0|
//+---+-----+----+
```

Comment: Oddly enough, I tried doing exactly that before, but for some reason the compiler was yelling at me saying I couldn't use the `over` method there. Hmm, now it's working. Well, thanks!